# Enforce and check JSON format in Azure Table Storage

Tags: json, azure, azure-table-storage, robo3t

Currently, I use Azure Table Storage to store some configuration data (see below for an example). The data is kind of unstructured, so I store it into the table using JSON. The whole document is stored in a database field.

```
{
    "group1": [
      "value1",
      "value2",
      "value3",
      "subgroup": [
          "value1",
          "value2"
        ]
    ],
    "othergroup": [
      "value1"
    ]
}
```

**Is there a way to at least enforce a valid JSON string to be stored in the database?** Because Table Storage under the hood store is as a string, there is no validity with respect to JSON at all. Neither is the JSON automatically formatted. [image: JSON not formatted and checked]

Previously at another project I worked with MongoDB and Studio 3T and was really happy with how you could manage JSON in it. Then, it was simply not possible to store an invalid JSON string into MongoDB.

However, Studio 3T is not usable for Table Storage, as far as I know..

Comment: You’d need to validate your data yourself; Table Storage doesn’t provide any such validation , since properties are just strings (as you’ve pointed out). There are all sorts of libraries across many programming languages for JSON. Perhaps look into finding one that suits this use case...

Comment: @David Makogin thanks, makes sense. I was hoping that Azure Storage Explorer (or some other (non-custom-made) tool would support JSON validation, as when adding data a syntax error will slip through quickly.

Comment: Table Storage is a key/value type of no-sql store. If you want to store a Jason document a document store like the cosmos DB mongodb api

Comment: @WoutervanKoppen, Hello, since this is by design, could you please accept it as an answer? It would be helpful to others. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to summarize, Azure table storage / Azure Storage Explorer does not support json validation.

It's properties are just strings for no-sql storage. As of now, you should implement your own logic for json validation.

Hope it can help others who have the same issue.